# Query to show all rows from sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your guide here... I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE t1.A = t2.A)
  AND T1.B = '123';
```

The scenario is to show some records from T2 with correct number of records shown. Could you help, please?

I have tried the below query, but it returns lots of duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM SAMP_TASK T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN QUOTE_TASK T2 ON T1.A=T2.A AND T1.B = '123';
```

Comment: Can you please edit to using the same table names and condition literals in both queries?

Comment: in order not to show the same record more than once you can use DISTINCT. Could you explain what the queries should accomplish?

Comment: how many rows it returned? And what is the expected count of rows?

Comment: what do you want to select?

Comment: @irina: hi thank you for comments, 1st query return 9 records, 2nd query return 15 records -- it should return 9 records

Comment: @Jarlh: both query are the same, the different is the result i wrote T1.B   = 'XXX'; and T1.B = '123';

Comment: And why do you want to confuse us doing that? Make it clear and simple, same table names and same literals in both queries please.

Comment: @ audhie So you want the second query to be like the first query?

Comment: i have edit my question, i hope it does not make you confuse.. sorry

Comment: @IrinaAvram: the 2nd query is the other way around that i have try... but it show junk records, the 1st query is good one, but i cant find a way to show records from table T2

Comment: you could use GROUP BY, I think, but I am not sure what the problem is

Comment: so wait, does it show duplicates or other records?

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thanks for the feed back, i have solved by using other table to link these 2 tables. thank you for your feedback guys